# File storage server

Tags: java, mongodb, caching, memcached

I'm looking for cleaner way to horizontally scale my Java app with minimal impact in sources and infrastructure. Here is my problem: I'm currently saving resources in local file system, so i need to **consistently** share these files among all my new processing processing nodes.
I know the existence of ehcache and terractora server array but localRestartable (persistence guaranteed) is only available on ehcache enterprise and i want to keep commercial licenses as away as possible.
Other alternatives could be memcached, redis, mongodb (persistence in mind), even nfs, but i want the opinion of those who have experience using these services as storage services, also i need to clarify: Requirements prevent to use any on-line cloud storage service although i'm open to any alternative that could be installable on my data-center of course!.

Comment: How big are the resource files that you are replicating?  Do these need to end up in the file system for your application to manipulate, or are you able to work with data loaded directly from a data store?

Comment: Files are generally small, ~1mb. I can manage to load resources directly from a data store, i think it wont be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MongoDB you can take advantage of:

- [replica sets](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replica+Sets) to distribute data to multiple servers
- [sharding](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding) to scale writes (if appropriate for the volume of data and writes you need to manage)

You have a few options for storing your binary files in MongoDB:

1) You could save the files as binary data within a field in a MongoDB document.  The current document size limit (as at MongoDB 2.2) is 16Mb, which seems more than adequate for your ~1Mb files.

2) You can use the [GridFS API](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS) to conveniently work with larger documents or fetch binary files in smaller chunks (see also: [Java docs for the GridFS class](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/gridfs/GridFS.html)).

Comment: Is there any significant performance difference by choosing gridfs over binary file representation in mongodb?

Comment: I'm not aware of any relative performance benchmarks for using a single binary field versus GridFS. The [GridFS spec](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS+Specification) breaks files up into smaller chunks (usually 256k) which can help for concurrency when writing very large files but does have some presumed overhead to reconstitute the file. The GridFS implementation also takes care of storing the files and metadata, so is easy to implement.  For your ~1 Mb files, it may be more convenient to work with them in a single document. I would test both approaches to see what suits.